# Flash Esp-01 and Esp-12 using NodeMCU module

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am building a test IOT architecture. At the moment I do have a NodeMCU "Amica" V1 module (more will come) and some ESP-01. I have not yet tried to flash the ESP-01 because the MCU is just so user friendly, while buying 6 MCU is more pricey than .

I was wondering, if I do de-solder the ESP-12 from the NodeMCU and then connect a female receptacle for the ESP-01 to the now empty MCU breakout board, would i be able to flash the ESP-01 from the Arduino IDE? 
Would it maintain the automatic Reset and Flash pulls (as on the stock ESP-12)?
Will it also work with a pogo-pin assembly to flash other ESP-07/12 ?

Approximate answers and thoughts are well accepted, thank you very much.

Comment: look it up, it's open source hardware: https://smartarduino.gitbooks.io/user-manual-for-esp-12e-devkit/content/schematics_for_esp-12e_devkit.html

Answer (score 2):

On [this site](https://www.hackster.io/rayburne/esp8266-01-using-arduino-ide-67a124) there's a description of how to use a USB-serial adapter to flash a ESP-01 with the Arduino IDE. I'm not very familiar with the NodeMCU boards, but I imagine that they contain a USB-serial chip, and thus it *is* possible to desolder the ESP-12 and connect a ESP-01 (with cables or an adapter with pogo-pins) and program it that way. I'm not sure about the Reset/Flash pulls, but I imagine that it could be possible, study the pinouts for the ESP-12 and ESP-01 and circuitry for flashing (see the link). I did flash my ESP-01 this way, before I got other ESP8266 boards.

I would only do this operation if I was very handy with a soldering iron and the NodeMCU/ESP-12 was something that could go to waste if anything went wrong.

I think picking up a 3.3V LDO and USB-serial (3.3v!) breakout much easier, and more failproof, so that's what I'd recommend.